# Check if string in path and do something

Tags: python

Im trying to check if a word is inside a path and if `True` do something but it always returns False.

For example, my main path is `C:/Users/aka/Desktop/Imagenes` and some of the subfolders and files are:

```
C:/Users/aka/Desktop/Imagenes/Show
C:/Users/aka/Desktop/Imagenes/Show/geo
C:/Users/aka/Desktop/Imagenes/Other/geo/ha.jpg
C:/Users/aka/Desktop/Imagenes/Other
C:/Users/aka/Desktop/Imagenes/Other/ramdomfiles
C:/Users/aka/Desktop/Imagenes/Other/ramdomfiles/lo.jpg
```

and with this function I want to do somthing but only with the paths that contains the string `Other` for example, but it always go to the else statement and gives me `File in folder: Show File in folder: Other` any ideas on how can I make this work ?

```
def generate_tree(path,string):
    text=''
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        rel = path + "/" + file
        print(rel)
        if  string in rel and os.path.isdir(rel):   
            text += ' Main folder: ' +file
            text += generate_tree(rel,string)
        else:
            text += ' File in folder: '+file
    return text
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: for the string `Other` would be ` 'Main folder: Other Main folder: ramdomfiles File in folder: lo.jpg File in folder: lu.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `.split('/')` after `rel` in the `if` statement.

```py
def generate_tree(path,string):
    text=''
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        rel = path + "/" + file
        print(rel)
        if  string in rel.split('/') and os.path.isdir(rel):   
            text += ' Main folder: ' +file
            text += generate_tree(rel,string)
        else:
            text += ' File in folder: '+file
    return text
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is here:

```
rel = path + "/" + file
```

I'm guessing you're on Windows, where the path delimiter is a backslash.  For better results, try this:

```
rel = os.path.join(path, file)
```